# Fish eye rest API EQL query not returning the changeset

Tags: rest, web-services, http, atlassian-fisheye

I'm currently trying to retrieve all the changes made in july 2015 in our svn repo, however the following query does not retrieve all the required changesets, i.e. it retrieves all the changeset from 17th july until 31st july, However there exists some changes made on 10th july also, which is not returned.

```
http://scm.prod.org.zzz/viewer/rest-service-fe/search-v1/query/prod?queryAsRows=select revisions where date in [ 2015-07-01, 2015-07-31] group by changeset return csid, author, date, comment
```

Could anyone point out what could be the possible issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Re-scan` in repository maintenance section in Fisheye administration. You have to tell from what changeset it should reindex, so be sure to choose something that was submitted before the one you are looking for.